# (Python) Adding elements to the list using loop, appending to this list actual state of processing element after every iteration

Tags: python, list, loops

Hello i'm fighting with one kata on Codewars.
My idea is to create list of coordinates based on list of directions(NORTH,SOUTH...) but here a have a problem.
I'm going to use loop while, to check every direction  and simultaneously appending created coordinates to list t.
But I'm surprised because my loop doesn't append coordinates to t just after creating, but add final result of all iterations of the loop.
Could you explain me how it works and how can I add result of particular iterartion of loop to list t?

```
def dirReduc(arr):
    t=[[0,0]]

    a=[0,0]
    b=0
    while b<len(arr):

         if arr[b]=='NORTH':
            print(b)

            a[0]=a[0]+1
            print(a)
            t.append(a)

        b=b+1
    print(t)



print(dirReduc(["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]))
# I wish to modify this to [[0,0],[1,0],[0,0],[-1,0],[-1,1],[-1,0],[0,0],[0,-1]]
# if 'North' [a+1,b], if 'South' [a-1,b],if 'West' [a,b-1],if 'East' [a,b+1]
```

```
Run:
0
[1, 0]
5
[2, 0]
[[0, 0], [2, 0], [2, 0]] #here i suspect:[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0]]
None
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are appending `a` to the list, you are appending the reference [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/3923163), not the "snapshot in time" that you think you are getting. You need to instead use `copy()`:

```
t.append(a.copy())
```